# Bullet proof jquery image loading routine

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know this is a commonly asked question, but has anybody got a bullet proof jquery routine for checking if images load successfully, and if they don't, do something about it. I've tried a number of ideas posted on here and other forums. I've also tried a couple of plugins, imagesLoaded and waitForImages, all of which seems to have holes which mean some broken images go undetected. Can anybody advise please? Thanks.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$(function() {
    $(".vehicleImage").one("load", function() {
        // Image loaded successfully
        };
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    }).error(function () {  
        // Image didn't load, so do something about it
    })
});
```

Comment: Detect for any images that don't load from a collection of images. I've edited my original post to show the code I'm using at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-on-for-delegated-image-load-events

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361973/jquery-catching-an-image-load-event-error-404-can-it-be-done

Comment: Thanks for the response @m90, but the one article just says not to use .one and use some form of backend method, which is not an option for me. The other says to use something like $('img').bind('error', function() {
   alert('image did not load');
});       Which I understood as not being reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a technique from [Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/) which works very well: https://gist.github.com/2028925

Remy creates a new Image object in JavaScript and wraps that in jQuery instead of working with an img element from the DOM.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. But I'm trying to get my head around why that would be better?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why it would be. Certainly, I haven't come across any issues with it not handling broken images correctly. Thought it might be worth trying was a slightly different approach.

Comment: Looks like it's worth try. Thanks for your help.